# What does initialisation with struct prefix mean?

Tags: c, sockets, struct

I was reading some code and came across the following statement:

```
 struct sockaddr_in server
```

I understand that `sockaddr_in` is some predefined `struct` but why do we put `struct` as a prefix? Also shown below, a similar thing is attempted

[image]

Cannot I just write:

```
sockaddr_in server
```

Comment: I feel like [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612350/8147455), although about C++, answers your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Comment: @Xatyrian This one is about C, the other one about C++.

Comment: Yes but the accepted answer is about C

Comment: We write `struct` because it is a structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax of the C language requires that a declaration of a variable of a `struct` type include the `struct` keyword before the type.

While C++ *does* allow this keyword to be omitted, C does not.

Answer (score 1):

In C there is such a notion as a tag of a structure, union or enumeration. Correspondingly an identifier can denote a tag. To distinguish such an identifier from an identifier of other variable identifiers that denote tags are used together with keywords struct, union, and enum.

For example consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    struct x
    {
        int x;
    } x = { 10 };

    printf( "x.x = %d\n", x.x );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
x.x = 10
```

Here the same name `x` is used to denote a structure tag, a member of a structure and a variable of a structure type.

In C++ there is used the term class name the same way as a name of any other entity. In C++ there are name spaces that allows to place entities with the same name in different name space to avoid a collision.